# How to remove single quotes from string inside curly braces? (python, yaml)

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I'm using pyyaml. And writing code that will convert user information into yaml file of certain style. And I have certain requirements. Like some strings should have single qoutation, some double quotation and the rest should have no quotation mark at all, but they do.

I want achieve the following output in the yaml file:

```
class: {child}
```

But I get this:

```
class: '{child}'
```

How can I get rid of single quotes here? And it does same for 'false'/'true'. It keeps quotes.

I am using python 3.9,PyYAML 6.0

, thanks in advance.

*Some updates.
What I used to do is:

```
data = {}
data.update({'dev_class' : '{child}'})
```

And dump it

```
with open("package.yaml", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    yaml.dump(data,f, allow_unicode=True,encoding='utf-8',sort_keys=False, width=float("inf"))
```

That will result as I already mentioned:

```
dev_class: '{child}'
```

I tried to manipulate with string itself using str(), replace(), and so on. It had no result. Then since I am kinda declaring a set, I decide to add not a string, but a set.

```
data.update({'dev_class' : {'moisture'}})
```

And I received the following:

```
dev_class: !!set
o:
e:
t:
m:
i:
s:
u:
r:
```

So, I still in search.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'class: \'{child}\''

print(s.replace('\'', ''))
```

**Edit1:**

```
import yaml

data = {}
data.update({'dev_class' : '{child}'})

str_data = ""
for i in data:
    str_data += i + ": " + data[i]

with open("package.yaml", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    yaml.dump(str_data,f, allow_unicode=True,encoding='utf-8',sort_keys=True, width=float("inf"))
```

Comment: When I dumping some information into yaml file using python, I am using dictionary. So, basically it looks like this:
    `data = {}`
    `data.update({'class' : '{child}'})`
I've tried to do the way you told
    `data.update({'class' : '\'{child}\''.replace('\'','')})`
but the result was the same.

Comment: @Unknown_ Try it right now, so you need to put dict data in str type!

Comment: No...it raises TypeError. You sre not allowed to concatenate dict with str. Only str with str. But anyway, thanks for help.